# HTML element keyboard shortcut without alt key

Tags: html, access-keys

I have a button that is accessed by a keyboard shortcut but the users have to press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. Is there anyway to let the users access the button by simply pressing <kbd>Z</kbd> (or some other key) without having to press <kbd>ALT</kbd>?

Many thanks,

```
<input style="display:none;" id='stopButton1' type="button" value="Z" onclick="stop('z')" accesskey="z" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that is not possible in pure HTML.

JavaScript is needed: Use the `keypress` event to detect specific character codes, and call some function.

Comment: give any example/syntax

Comment: nice to know we can use it without jquery plugin

Answer (score 1):

We can use `jquery 2.1.3` plugin and `keypress` with `ASCII` value

JS:

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 72 || e.which==104) {
        window.location.replace("http://soluvations.in");
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<p>Press H/h to go to Home Page</p>
```

Here is 
[JSFIDDLE link](http://jsfiddle.net/pradeep1008/2L3xxd9d/)

Answer (score 1):

I landed on this page looking for a quick way to make accesskey operate without the modifier (alt) key.

If anyone else is looking for the same, I have added this to my page:

```js
  $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    var link = $("a[accesskey=" + e.key + "]");
    if (link.length) {
      window.location = link.attr('href');
    }
  });
```

This will capture keypresses, and if there is a link with that `accesskey` set, it will redirect to its `href`.